# Regarding delegation pattern in java

Tags: java

What I have grasped from the delegation pattern is that  class (ClassA) that does what another class (ClassB) does. ClassA also has to do more things (have more methods) than what ClassB does. You might be tempted to simply have ClassA subclass ClassB. Resist this temptation, becuase it is the wrong thing to do. Inheritance is inherently slow,The correct design involves defining a data member of type ClassB in ClassA. This way, you have eliminated the need for subclassing and reduced the coupling strength

```
   //ClassA
 public class ClassA{

      private ClassB classB;

      //methods
      public void doThis(){classB.doThis();}
      public void doThat(){…}
  }
```

and here is the class B

```
    ClassB
  public class ClassB{
      public void doThis(){…}
  }
```

Please advise is my understanding is correct.

Comment: This sounds roughly correct, though I don't see a real question here.

Comment: There are many reasons for choosing delegation over inheritance, but I wouldn't say that performance is one of them.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks could you please tell what are those reasons of not choosing inheritance for making classes more cohesive..!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. In your question, you seem to assert that you should not use inheritance because it's inherently slow (which is arguable), and thus that you should choose delegation instead. My point is that sometimes inheritance is the right solution, and often delegation is the right solution. But the choice of one over the other has nothing to do with one being faster than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking what is the difference between [inheritance and composition](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html). Both of these patterns have their own use case. [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) suggests you should use inheritance when two objects have a true 'is a' relationship. So for example a rectangle is a shape. So it should probably extend shape. However, there are cases where people misunderstand this theory and still extend when they should really be composing another object. The advantages are of course decoupling and better design in the future. The textbook example is extending `HashMap` in java. Instead of extends, one can implement `Map` and just have a composed `HashMap` that does the actual logic.

I recommend you read Effective Java and understand what the advantages of both patterns are.